# mesh indexing overhead in compute kernel

Tags: ios, metal

I have a compute kernel which operates on the triangles of a mesh. According to the profiler, the looking up of vertex positions is over half the runtime:

```
int a = indices[idx];  
int b = indices[idx+1];    // 0.7 %  
int c = indices[idx+2];    // 0.1 %  

Vertex v0 = vertices[ a ];      // 39.8 %  
Vertex v1 = vertices[ b ];      //  7.3 %  
Vertex v2 = vertices[ c ];      //  3.9 %
```

Where `Vertex` is as follows:

```
struct Vertex {
    packed_float3 position;
    packed_float3 normal;
};
```

Is there a way I can improve this?

Should I switch to a "triangle soup" representation (no indexing) at the cost of rendering performance?

Could I implement a cache of vertices somehow?

Should I try processing more than one triangle in the compute kernel and reuse vertices if the indices match (my mesh will have indices shared between consecutive triangles)?

**Update**: What I also find interesting is that, in my profile, rendering takes .9ms (the mesh isn't that big) and this compute kernel which iterates over triangles takes 11ms. The fast rendering performance would indicate that there's no big problem with the locality of my mesh, since rendering has to do the same indexing. I suspect that the massive performance difference is due to the vertex cache.

**Update 2**: I managed to overlook the following warning:

> warning: The Compiler was not able to Preload your Buffer: The compiler was not able to preload your buffer at index 0 in the kernel function. Simplify your memory access pattern by using the constant address space, a struct, or a descriptor. (This pipeline was not used in this frame).

There are warnings for both `vertices` and `indices`. I don't see how I could use a struct or constant address space, but what about a descriptor? I'm not sure how to use a descriptor in a compute kernel.

Comment: I suspect that the stack allocation on the line above the "heavy" line is actually the issue. Is there a way to transform the work such that you can avoid those temporary `Vertex` objects?

Comment: @warrenm I used three variables for the vertices instead and there wasn't a significant change in the profile. Was hoping that was it!

Comment: What address space qualifier (e.g. `device` or `constant`) are you using for `vertices`?

Comment: @KenThomases `device`

Comment: Hello @Taylor! I'm stuck with very simillar problem and I wonder if you solved an issue. If you got through this, can you give me some tips? Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev I'm afraid I switched to a volumetric representation and no longer do this. Sorry!